# How to compare two lists and update a list value

Tags: c#, list

Hi i am trying the below requirement.

class:

```
public class Items
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }


    }
```

list1:

```
        ID NAME type
        1  aaa  1a
        2  bbb  2b
        3  ccc  3b
```

list2:

```
        ID NAME 
        1a  aaa  
        2b  bbb  
        3c  ccc 
        4d  ddd
        5e  eee
        6f  fff
```

Compare the two lists list1 and list2.

i am trying the below query
Compare the two lists list1 and list2.

```
List<Items> list3= list2.Where(x => list1.Any(z=>x.id==z.type)).ToList();
```

i am getting the below result for above query:

```
        ID NAME 
        1a  aaa  
        2b  bbb  
        3c  ccc
```

expected result:
i want the list1 ID, list2 Name where list1.type==list2.ID to form the list3 like below

```
list3:
    
        ID NAME 
        1  aaa  
        2  bbb  
        3  ccc
```

Any Help or Suggestion to the above query.
Thanks,
Sudha.

Comment: Fliip it round `list1.Where(x => list2.Any(...`. For performance reasons you probably want the inner list to be a `HashSet`

Answer (score 1):

Join two lists on values of `id` and `type` fields and then select desired result:

```
from l1 in list1
join l2 in list2 on l1.type equals l2.id
select new { l1.id, l1.name }
```

In the select operator you can select whole `l1`, or create non-anonymous type instance. Same in method syntax:

```
list1.Join(list2, l1 => l1.type, l2 => l2.id, (l1, l2) => new { l1.id, l1.name })
```

Note: use PascalCase naming for properties.